# Tools for analysing experimental data

Tags: scientific-computing

What tools are there for analysing experimental data with a number of variables to attempt to optimise parameters for a particular parameter? This question is purposely general - I'm more asking for tools that I should look at in the future, than tools to use now.

**Related Questions**

- [Existence of a table generation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591864/existance-of-a-table-generation-framework-for-experiments)

Comment: Are you trying to fit a parameterized model to your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as free tools go, I second Dirk's suggestion of [R](http://www.r-project.org/), but I'd like to mention [Python](http://www.python.org/) and the [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) library (in particular, the [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) package) as a possible alternative.  It would help of you could be more specific as to what kind of data analysis you are trying to do so that we can be more specific with our recommendations.

Comment: I second your mention of Python, and would like to point out that if SciPy won't do everything that you need, you will probably find it easier to use Rpy2 to interface to R rather than having to learn the R language itself. The R language was designed by statisticians, not programmers, so a developer will get more done, more quickly with Python than with R.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [**R**](http://www.r-project.org)? To quote from the FAQ:

> R is a system for statistical
>   computation and graphics.  It consists
>   of a language plus a run-time
>   environment with graphics, a debugger,
>   access to certain system functions,
>   and the ability to run programs stored
>   in script files.

Version 2.10.0 was released this week. About 2000 contributed packages are at the [**CRAN**](http://cran.r-project.org) mirror network.

Answer (score 1):

R's good, so is Matlab, Mathematica, even Excel.